# Getting relative image src with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got image tags that look like this:

```
<img src="/path/to/my/image.jpg" />
```

But when I access the src bit using jQuery, jQuery gives me back:

```
http://example.com/path/to/my/image.jpg
```

This is causing problems in some comparisons I'm doing. I don't want to change my image paths to use absolute URLs.

Any ideas as to how I can either get the absolute URL from the image path (this might not be as simple as concatenating the domain - since the URLs may occasionally be absolute), or get the path I provided in the HTML? Either way I need them to match up.

#### Edit per comment from activa

There's not really a lot of jQuery code to post, I'm using the [cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin, and in the `onbefore` function, I'm just calling `next.src`. My jQuery and JavaScript foo isn't sufficient to really understand what the cycle plugin is doing to generate `next` - I think it's the DOM element for the next image being cycled in, if you're familiar with what cycle does.

My image tag is actually this:

```
<img src="/site_media/photologue/photos/cache/6927d406810ee9750a754606dcb61d28.jpg" alt="" class="landscape slideshow-image-1" />
```

and in my `onbefore` function this code:

```
alert(next.src);
```

results in an alert with:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/photologue/photos/cache/6927d406810ee9750a754606dcb61d28.jpg
```

Comment: Can you post the jQuery code you are using to retrieve the src attribute? Because this doesn't seem right. As Mario pointed out below, the src attribute will not be modified by jQuery

Comment: In my case I actually *wanted* the absolute URL, so I just did what were doing before you fixed it. Awesome :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$("img").attr("src")` gives back the actual value of the src attribute (tried in FF3 and IE7)

So when you have

```
<img src="http://example.com/path/to/my/image.jpg" />
```

it will return

```
http://example.com/path/to/my/image.jpg
```

And when you have

```
<img src="/path/to/my/image.jpg" />
```

it will return

```
/path/to/my/image.jpg
```

**Edit after edit of question**

Sounds like you may want to try

```
$(next).attr("src")
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you strip it?

```
var hostname = 'http://' + window.location.hostname;
```

it will assing to hostname

```
http://example.com
```

then refactor your variable like

```
if( imgSrc == imgSrc2 ) ...
```

to

```
if( ImgSource(imgSrc) == imgSrc2 ) ...
```

using

```
function ImgSource(path) {
    return hostname + path;
}
```

or the other way arround

```
function ImgSource(path) {
    return path.replace(hostname, '');
}
```

Comment: If you are testing on local machine you should use window.location.host to get the port number attached to the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

To always get the full resolved path, use `Element.src` , not `Element.getAttribute("src")` (which seems to be the equivalent of attr("src")).

E.g.:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src
```

rather than:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src")
```

.  I'll let you jqueryify .src.

Answer (score 0):

I have this happening on a page loaded via Ajax on a server that seems to be .NET based.  Even though the path is relative its returning the full URL even though in all other browsers it works fine.  Only happening in IE 8.  I can't strip off based on a domain since there are several environments for the project I'm working on.

I'll report back if I find anything better than just splitting or regex replacement.