# Absolute and relative paths in jquery

Tags: jquery, relative-path, attr, absolute-path

Why would the following two codes return the same result?

```
var img = new Image(400,250); 
        $(img).attr('src','resources/images/' + i + '.jpg');
```

And

```
var img = new Image(400,250); 
        img.src = 'resources/images/' + i + '.jpg';
```

I'm not good in jQuery so I searched the web for the differences and according to my findings I expected the first code to return: `resources/images/1.jpg` and the second one to return: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/resources/images/1.jpg`

I appreciate a clarification.

Comment: Seems like you have a copy paste error at `images/'+ i`  !== `images' + i`

Comment: I don't have this typo in my actual code. I edited my question to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.attr('src', newSource)` and `.src = newSource` are different in that one works with attributes (or more specifically, a serialization of the DOM), and the other with DOM properties.

jQuery's `.attr()` setter uses [`.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute), that is, it works with attributes. Attribute values are plain text which you normally write in the HTML: `<img src="someSource">`.

While the browser receives the HTML and parses it into DOM, the `src` attribute value is resolved relatively to the document's location (or `<base>` tag if any) and the resolved URI is set as the DOM image element's `src` property.

The `src` attribute reflects the `src` property, that is, a change in the `src` property value will be reflected in the `src` attribute value (and the other way around as well).

The `src` property always stores the resolved URI (setting it to a relative URI will implicitly resolve it according to document location/`base` tag) and a change in the property will be reflected in the attribute. The same happens the other way around (setting the property updates the attribute value).

---

### More important note

Independent of setting the attribute or the property, the resolved URI (which will be fetched from the server) **will be the same**. So all of this doesn't make much difference unless you have some code that tests attributes against specific values.

Comment: I don't use ie. I use firefox.

Comment: Yeah, I added one more note. If you have an issue with the browser not fetching the image, please update the question.

Answer (score 3):

The `urls` displayed above are both relative urls.  When resolved the `src` attribute will be combined with a base uri to form the actual uri used to locate the image.  If you want to reference the `src` attribute/property via Javascript use the following example to obtain the desired result:

There urls are resolved to the following:

```
var img = new Image(400,250); 
$(img).attr('src','resources/images/5.jpg');
$("body").append(img);

console.log($(img).attr("src"));
//prints: resources/images/5.jpg

console.log(img.src);
//prints: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/resources/images/5.jpg

console.log($(img).prop("src"));
//prints: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/resources/images/5.jpg
```

Comment: I know what relative and absolute URIs are. I wanted to know which of these codes_`img.src` or `$(img).attr("src")` returns absolute URI in jQuery. I guess they are not supposed to return the same result. Please look at this StackOverFlow question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948973/getting-relative-image-src-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948973/getting-relative-image-src-with-jquery) for example.

Comment: `img.src` provides the absolute uri, while `$(img).attr("src")` provides only the value specified for `src` or the relative url.  See the example I have posted or this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zs2wp/  To get the full resolved uri with jQuery use: `$(img).prop("src")`

Comment: Your question is answered in the page you link too....     **To always get the full resolved path, use Element.src**

Comment: So why would they give the same result in my browser? I get `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/myApp/resources/images/5.jpg"` in firebug for both of them.

Comment: @user2911374 because that's what the resolved URI is for both of them. I don't know what else you'd be expecting.

Comment: @user2911374 Because Firefox is resolving the url to locate the image.  Your question revolves around the difference between properties and attributes.  Attributes are what you see in markup.  Such as `<img src="resources/images/test.png"/>`, in this example `src` is an attribute, however when you change the `src` via Javascript `img.src = "/resources/images/test2.png"/>` your working with a property.  When its time for the browser to locate the resource, it adds the base uri to the relative path to locate the resource.  FireFox is displaying that resolved path.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté and Kevin Bowersox thanks for your replies. Both your answers are very helpful and detailed. I'm marking FabrícioMatté's answer for its detailed explanation. I learned many things about jQuery.

Comment: yay for $.prop()! i was looking to go the other way; i needed to always get the absolute path of an img on a page (from a bookmarklet) regardless of if the img src is relative or not. great answer @KevinBowersox